# Extra argument error

Tags: ios, swift, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a simple ios app and I keep getting an error as "Extra argument in call" when I'm passing the exact same values.

**TaskManager.swift**

```
struct task {
    var name = "Name"
    var desc = "Description"
}

var tasks = [task]()

class TaskManager: NSObject {

    func addTask(name: String, desc: String) {
        tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))
    }

}
```

The calling function is in another swift file,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTask: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtDesc: UITextField!
    @IBAction func btnAddTask(sender: UIButton) {
        if (txtTask.text != "") {
            TaskManager.addTask(txtTask.text, txtDesc.text)
            txtTask.text = nil
            txtDesc.text = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sending the exact same arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: structs should be named starting with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's expecting 1 argument, and that's an initialised Task Manager. You aren't initialising the Task Manager. If you want to do it like you are (not initialising it), make your method `static`:

```
static func addTask(etc..
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
TaskManager.addTask(2 args...
```

---

Or, keep it how it is and just initialise TaskManager:

```
let manager = TaskManager()
manager.addTask(etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Task {
    var name: String
    var desc: String
}

var tasks: [Task] = []

class TaskManager: NSObject {

    static func addTask(name: String, desc: String) {
        tasks += [task(name: name, desc: desc)]
    }   
}

TaskManager.addTask("someName", desc: "shouldn't this be a bool?")

print(tasks) // [task(name: "someName", desc: "shouldn\'t this be a bool?")]
```

Add `static` in front of `addTask(_:)` and it will work.

Comment: Haha, we were about the same I think. The only reason I posted this as an answer is his code was too messy and was itching me :p

Comment: structs should be named starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: @LeoDabus: Thanks, I missed that one :)

Comment: @Eendje Thanks for the answer! I'll try to make my code look neat in the future :p